Correctly passing a function as argument in Flutter
I want to pass a function as an argument (basically I want to modularize a button that needs a different 'onpressed' function in each instance). Whatever I do, either the function never gets executed or it gets executed as soon as the widget is built, but not when the button is pressed. So here's my code (abstraction):
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyButton(answerFunction: (){print('this works');},),
    );
  }
}

class MyButton extends StatelessWidget{
  MyButton({required this.answerFunction});

final Function() answerFunction;

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(child: 
      TextButton(onPressed: (){
        answerFunction;
        print('do some other stuff here');
      },
      child: Text('click'),),),
    );
  }
   
}


How do I pass any function correctly so it is only but definitely executed when the button is pressed?

you need to call answerFunction.call() inside TextButton onPressed

Change
answerFunction

to
answerFunction.call();


Oh wow, that simple, huh? I love it! Thanks a lot.

The .call is not required, you can just do answerFunction();

Yes, but I prefer call(). It's a little bit longer but easier to read
